# How to save the image inside a variable to a server location

Tags: php, html, image, codeigniter, file-upload

This is the value of variable which carrying an image. How can i save this to a server location using php?

```
data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAfQAAAD6CAYAAABXq7VOAAAgAElEQVR4XtS9CYxd13km+N1331asKpKSqMUyRVKkZNmSKImWRO1yvMTxFnlL4nacOE46PdONbkyjke6ZpCeTNKaBwWCABgaDAaYTTAODwaDTthVLXmJttqx9sSVZtkTtmy1RFCVxJ6vqbfcOvn8559z37itWSXSQLpuqqldvucs5//d/379lf/zHZ5cNZOBXGf6Tyc........
```

Comment: What you have done something?

Comment: Where is this variable? Is it on the server or external to the server ?

Comment: @AdhanTimothyYounes I just cropped an image using script and the result of the cropped image is getting like this. i want to save this to a folder location on web hosting server

Comment: @crazyglasses I just cropped an image using script and the result of the cropped image is getting like this. i want to save this to a folder location on web hosting server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this code.

```
$data = 'write your image code here';

list($type, $data) = explode(';', $data);

list(, $data)      = explode(',', $data);

$data = base64_decode($data);

file_put_contents('image.png', $data);
```